# how to automatically run a file off usb in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, autorun

I've been trying to automatically run an application off USB in windows 8.1. I thought of trying Autorun but windows has removed that feature. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Microsoft disabled it for the reason, that this was the way that a lot of malware was distributed. So why do you need this back?

Comment: i am in computer security course and learning a way around that just for the sake of knowing..... @magicandre1981